# Is there a way to tell byobu to use $HOME/.cache/byobu instead of /dev/shm/ even though I have /dev/shm available?

Tags: byobu

Is there a way to tell byobu to use $HOME/.cache/byobu instead of /dev/shm/ even though I have /dev/shm available?

I can see that byobu is currently using /dev/shm and from what I can tell in `/usr/lib/byobu/include/dirs` there is no way to override that. Am I missing something?